# File upload control for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, razor

I'm writing an asp.net mvc application. I'm looking for free control to make file(s) upload. (Multiple files upload is not required). I found uploadify, ajax uploader, c5 filemanager.
I'm looking rather example which I could include in Razor form and add additional fields such as i.e. file description.
Do you have any specific control which you could suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify in my opinion is the best.
Check out:
[How do I get jQuery's Uploadify plugin to work with ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002680/how-do-i-get-jquerys-uploadify-plugin-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc)

its the same in mvc3.