# MVC3 Multiple File Upload plugin that supports IE 9?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, plugins, file-upload, controls

I have been looking at file upload plugins that support multiple file to be uploaded but the majority of these plugins do not support IE9 (that is, you can't select multiple files in the select dialog).

Do not support IE9:
jquery file upload (per blueimp)
telerik open source

Can somebody provide plugin workarounds, suggestions, code examples?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.   Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uploadify. It is pretty awesome. Message me if you can't get it to work, but it is pretty straight forward if you read the documentation carefully!

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Cool, will this work Chrome/FF as well?

Comment: Sure, and also on Opera and IE

Comment: John, is there some canonical documentation that shows simple integration with mvc3 (with post backs)?  I don't need all of the views...since they will be custom.  I just need the ability to get back the files in a post back to process them.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, one thing that I did notice is that when running the following demo in IE9 I wasn't able to select multiple files within the dialog box (Chrome works fine).

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: Check this out http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7301/internet-explorer-9-problem/p1

Comment: Okay, this worked for me with latest flash in IE9. A little more help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002680/how-do-i-get-jquerys-uploadify-plugin-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), which gives you a HTML5 file upload control with various fallbacks (Flash, Silverlight, Gears) for older/unsupported browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I use [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers.fileupload%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) included in [Microsoft.Web.Helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) namespace. Works great with all modern browsers.

The good thing is that it's part of Microsoft web stack...

Sample view code:

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml(
                    initialNumberOfFiles: 3,
                    allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true,
                    includeFormTag: false,
                    addText: @Localization.AddAnotherPhoto,
                    uploadText: @Localization.UploadFile
                   )
```

Comment: Cool, will this work Chrome/FF as well?

Comment: This is great but the only problem is that it doesn't offer true multi-select of files.  It's somewhat of a psuedo-solution but I do appreciate the insight.